# Kafka with Docker 3 nodes in different host - Broker may not be available

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm played with wurstmeister/kafka image on three different docker host
, and hosts ip are

- `10.1.1.11`
- `10.1.1.12`
- `10.1.1.13`

I enter these command to run image:

- 10.1.1.11:

  ```
  sudo docker run --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --restart always \ 
    -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID="1" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="10.1.1.11" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT="9092" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="0.0.0.0:2181,10.1.1.12:2181,10.1.1.13:2181" \ 
    -d wurstmeister/kafka
  ```
- 10.1.1.12:

  ```
  sudo docker run --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --restart always \ 
    -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID="2" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="10.1.1.12" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT="9092" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="10.1.1.11:2181,0.0.0.0:2181,10.1.1.13:2181" \
    -d wurstmeister/kafka
  ```
- 10.1.1.13:

  ```
  sudo docker run --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --restart always \ 
    -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID="3" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="10.1.1.13" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT="9092" \ 
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="10.1.1.11:2181,10.1.1.12:2181,0.0.0.0:2181" \ 
    -d wurstmeister/kafka
  ```

When run those command, always the first command appear the:
 [image: Broker may not be available] 
Warning, the rest of two are not appear this question.

I'm using kafka producer test too. if host appear this problem, message send failed with message

[image: LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE]

if not appear this problem, message send success.

When I restart the image in `10.1.1.11`, the problem is fixed, but `10.1.1.12` start the same problem and so on.

All i search this problem solve method are set the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to docker host. But i already did.
I have no idea why appear this problem.

My Zookeeper command on `10.1.1.11`:

```
sudo docker run --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 \ 
  --restart always \ 
  -e ZOO_MY_ID="1" \
  -e ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=10.1.1.12:2888:3888 server.3=10.1.1.13:2888:3888" \
  -d zookeeper:latest
```

Comment: Probably you should go step-by-step: 1. setup a [standalone zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_InstallingSingleMode) (you are using the distributed mode by specifying multiple IPs in`ZOO_SERVERS`) 2. Try to only connect one kafka instance to the zookeeper and if this works, add second kafka-node, if this works, it is easy to scale to a multi-node cluster (with 3 or more nodes). If you have problems with one step, you can create a new question

Comment: Thanks @Murmel , I will try it.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from OP.*

The problem was firewall block docker container connect to docker host.
so i can't telnet docker host inside docker container.
the solution was set rule to iptables

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i <docker-bridge-interface> -j ACCEPT
```

I found solution from https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24370